# Textbox created in WPF is not editable at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am creating a WPF Window in which I have text boxes. However, when I run the project in Debug mode, (F5), I am not able to edit the text boxes that I created, nor am I able to choose from the listbox that I created. I googled, found that WPF and Win32 need to communicate to accept keyboard input, and got these 3 lines :

```
Window w = new Window1();
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(w);
w.Show();
```

However, I am new to C# and hence I have absolutely no idea where to insert this C# code. I added the System.Windows.Forms and WindowsFormIntegration references to my project.

The window I am designing will be the first window that will appear at the launch of the application, hence I need the textboxes in this window to be editable without launching another window. Kindly guide me.

Edit : This is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Name="Window1" x:Class="Myproject.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Risk Assessment"
Height="741" Width="1216.091">

<GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Length"  IsReadOnly ="False" IsEnabled="True" />
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
</Window>
```

This is my C# code:

```
namespace Myproject
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {   
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();        
       }
   }
}
```

Edit 2: I modified the first line in the App.Xaml code like this :

```
<Application x:Class="Myproject.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
```

And in the App.Xaml.cs I added this snippet:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
        ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(win);
        win.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

But still no luck. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I see no TextBox here. What are you trying to achieve with the ElementHost thingy?

Comment: I have XAML code for my textbox. When I scoured the internet, all it offered me was the above 3 lines of code, to enable a WPF window accept text input through a textbox. However, what I don't know is where to add these 3 lines of code. That's where I was hoping I'd get some help.

Comment: post Window1 XAML , you can delete the second line if you are just trying to create a window with some textboxes in WPF

Comment: I have added my code in the question, check it out! The second line is what will help me get user input into the text box right? I need to know where to add those 3 lines in the C# code that I have posted, since Window1 will be the first one to appear when the project is run!

Comment: Your first snippet of code is only needed in certain cases where you're mixing WPF with non-WPF code, e.g. if you're showing WPF UI from a WinForms app or from an ActiveX control. If you're writing a regular WPF app, you do *not* need anything from `System.Windows.Forms.Integration`.

Comment: If that is the case, then why is my textbox still not editable at run time? Kindly have a look at my Myproject XAML and Myproject C# code. Nevertheless, you offered me a new ray of hope. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `Application.xaml` to include the `StartupUri`:

```
<Application x:Class="Myproject.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     StartupUri="Window1.xaml"
>
```

Remove all the startup code you had in the cs file.

*Or*

Change your cs code to this:

```
Window1 window1 = new Window1();
this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
this.MainWindow = window1;
```